# Creating Document in CosmosDB with postman Error

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am able to create the DB and the collection via postman, however when I try to create a document I get this error.

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The collection cannot be accessed with this SDK version as it was created with newer SDK version.\"]}\r\nActivityId: e0cbc782-c764-48c8-bce4-8e1d5bf21da4, Request URI: /apps/06f97901-5530-4c65-a094-ceac7aeba20b/services/742a131c-0991-499c-bd7c-1e899c09b61c/partitions/45855936-11ca-4b85-b2b5-a69e6c0d1f11/replicas/132816360009752188p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739709Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039391Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\n{\"systemHistory\":[{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:21:25.4530841Z\",\"cpu\":0.744,\"memory\":52690489344.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.0204,\"availableThreads\":32764,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}},{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:21:35.4632206Z\",\"cpu\":1.625,\"memory\":50108911616.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.0137,\"availableThreads\":32743,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}},{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:21:45.4733865Z\",\"cpu\":0.886,\"memory\":50303107072.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.02,\"availableThreads\":32765,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}},{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:22:05.4836759Z\",\"cpu\":0.658,\"memory\":50759467008.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.0174,\"availableThreads\":32765,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}},{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:22:15.4937953Z\",\"cpu\":1.056,\"memory\":50995646464.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.0166,\"availableThreads\":32762,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}},{\"dateUtc\":\"2021-11-17T15:22:25.5038872Z\",\"cpu\":2.251,\"memory\":50450370560.000,\"threadInfo\":{\"isThreadStarving\":\"False\",\"threadWaitIntervalInMs\":0.0215,\"availableThreads\":32765,\"minThreads\":52,\"maxThreads\":32767}}]}\r\nRequestStart: 2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739709Z; ResponseTime: 2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739709Z; StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westus2-fd22.documents.azure.com:14093/apps/ad7b049e-a5b5-477b-ad5c-689b7e77e42a/services/c39381b9-f255-469c-a031-699608b1c00c/partitions/32e095ed-ac4c-48d3-a03a-9fbf0ee34219/replicas/132814791013059696p/, LSN: -1, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: False, StatusCode: 410, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: , UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, BELatencyMs: , ActivityId: e0cbc782-c764-48c8-bce4-8e1d5bf21da4, TransportRequestTimeline: {\"requestTimeline\":[{\"event\": \"Created\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739709Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.0105},{\"event\": \"ChannelAcquisitionStarted\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739814Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.009},{\"event\": \"Pipelined\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7739904Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.097},{\"event\": \"Transit Time\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7740874Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.4853},{\"event\": \"Received\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7745727Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.0257},{\"event\": \"Completed\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:27.7745984Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0}],\"requestSizeInBytes\":1137,\"requestBodySizeInBytes\":635,\"responseMetadataSizeInBytes\":56,\"responseBodySizeInBytes\":75};\r\n ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\r\nRequestStart: 2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039391Z; ResponseTime: 2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039391Z; StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westus2-fd37.documents.azure.com:14034/apps/06f97901-5530-4c65-a094-ceac7aeba20b/services/742a131c-0991-499c-bd7c-1e899c09b61c/partitions/45855936-11ca-4b85-b2b5-a69e6c0d1f11/replicas/132816360009752188p/, LSN: 1, GlobalCommittedLsn: 1, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 1, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, BELatencyMs: 0.298, ActivityId: e0cbc782-c764-48c8-bce4-8e1d5bf21da4, TransportRequestTimeline: {\"requestTimeline\":[{\"event\": \"Created\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039391Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.0101},{\"event\": \"ChannelAcquisitionStarted\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039492Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.0099},{\"event\": \"Pipelined\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8039591Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.1055},{\"event\": \"Transit Time\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8040646Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.8552},{\"event\": \"Received\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8049198Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0.041},{\"event\": \"Completed\", \"startTimeUtc\": \"2021-11-17T15:22:28.8049608Z\", \"durationInMs\": 0}],\"requestSizeInBytes\":1137,\"requestBodySizeInBytes\":635,\"responseMetadataSizeInBytes\":173,\"responseBodySizeInBytes\":112};\r\n ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"
}
```

The x-ms-version header is the same for all my requests.

Here is an image of the headers and call I use for creating a collection.

[image]

for creating a document I change my url to:

```
https://<url>.documents.azure.com/dbs/volcanodb2/colls/testcol2/docs
```

for the body I use the examples found on the msft docs:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document
```

This is my pre-request script:

```
var today = new Date();
var str = today.toUTCString();
pm.environment.set("time", str);

// I need these to generate a token
var verb = 'POST'; 
var resourceType = "docs"; 
var resourceId = 'dbs/volcanodb2/colls/testcol2'; 
var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + (resourceId || "") + "\n" + str.toLowerCase() + "\n" + "" + "\n";

//Hash and Encode by using the masterkey.
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("<my token here>"); 
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 
var MasterToken = "master"; 
var TokenVersion = "1.0"; 
var authToken = encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);

// Save it to parameter to use in HTTP header
pm.environment.set("authToken", authToken);
```

UPDATE: SS to repsonse.
[image]

The body I am using is, I also tried the one posted in the docs:

```
{  
  "id": "AndersenFamily"
}
```

Comment: I see an unauthorized error though in the screen shot

Comment: that is because I changed my url to show <url>  it works when I add my actual cosmodb url. I am able to succesfully create a db and a collection.  The bad request error I posted only shows up for creating a document.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing few headers which are missing in your screenshot?

```
Accept : application/json
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey : ["yourPK"]
x-ms-verison : 2016-07-11
```

Comment: same error, updated with SS.

Comment: you created collection with postman?

Comment: yes I created it with postman

Comment: can you try the sample attached here https://github.com/sajeetharan/CosmosDBPostmanGuide

Comment: When I follow your steps I am getting 407 authentication required for the trying to get DBS.

Comment: make sure the settings are correct, i tested now and it works

Comment: I couldnt get it to work so I copied your pre-request script to replace mine.  I changed your RFC1123time to time like in mine.  I have the same headers as the screenshot above and I still get the same error.  Could it be something related to settings when the resource was created?

Comment: could be that? can you try creating with the same settings as above

Comment: Please avoid having conversations in comments. Either move this to [chat] or at least remove old comments to remain focused on a specific answer.